how to stop autopost back on dropdown selection in dotnet core application
`
  <select class="form-select" id="financialYears" onchange="preventAutopostBack(event)">
       @{
           // Get the current year
           var currentYear = 2024;

           // Generate options for the last 5 years dynamically
           for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
           {
               var startYear = currentYear - i;
               var endYear = startYear + 1;
               var financialYear = $"{startYear}-{endYear}";

               if (i == 0) // Check if it's the first option (current year)
               {
                   <option value="@financialYear" selected>@financialYear</option>
               }
               else
               {
                   <option value="@financialYear">@financialYear</option>
               }
           }
       }
   </select>`

how to stop autopost back on dropdown selection in dotnet core application and i use jquery and javascript with it is not working at all

What's causing the postback in the first place?  A <select> by itself does not submit a form or perform any navigation action when selecting a value.

what does your preventAutopostBack JS function look like?  it should be something like
<script>
    function preventAutopostBack(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
</script>


yes,but it is not working

how about just do it inline <select class="form-select" id="financialYears" onchange="event.preventDefault();"

still same issue its not working

throw me a bone man, its not working is not very helpful



i provide select command and js
